# UK refusal, no ecnomic or financial ties

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I applied for  UK business visitor visa for 1 week only, I supplied all the documents including the invitation letter from the company I'm going to visit. ECO said I'm not satisfied about my ecnomic and social ties in my home country.

My supervisor wrote in his letter that I'm doing my PhD and I have 3 kids who will be here during my travel with my wife and she is also doing her Ph.D, however, I did not attach any proof for my kids nor my wife in the first time, I did so only for myself as I did not know.

Anyway I'm going to re apply and this time will provide all documents along with my kids school registration.

For ecnomic ties I'm going to provide my ownership of two appartments in my home country.

I also attached our collaborative work with the company I'm going to visit (scientific publications).

For sure we did flights and hotel reservations in the first time.

We prepared new letters from our side and the accommodating company side as well to give more details of the visit.

Do I have to do anything else?

Thanks

Comment: For a UK Standard Visit visa application, it is not necessary to provide confirmation of flights and accommodation https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf In fact, UKVI specifically advises that you should not book these before receiving your visa.  You’ll get a fuller answer if you post a copy of the refusal notice with personal information blanked out.

Comment: Do you have bank statements? Two apartments, wife and kids seem to be social/property ties to your home country, but if you cannot prove you can afford the trip, it is not going to work out.

Comment: Yes, I will provide my bank statement, however, the accommodating company stated in their letter that they will cover all the expenses, even they did book rge hotel and the flight

Comment: Don't bother showing travel docs, they specifically told you not to book flight and hotel before getting a visa, and it makes you sound like someone who does not follow instructions, and is therefore desperate.  Do research all the financial statements they want to see, and provide them all.

Comment: Also two apartments muddies  the water, makes you look like a landlord rather than a homeowner. Make clear you live in one of them.

Comment: But I'm really a landlord I'm not living in any of them I rented them out, and they actually want to see that I have something in my hometown (like source of income) and I will leave UK, so I'm supporting such proofs for this reason (ecnomic ties), in addition to school proofs for my kids and university proof for my wife. Regarding the hotel and tickets they were booked by the accommodating company not myself, and from the beginning I prepared my documents based on the advice of an agent who made the application for me and asked for hotel and flights booking.

Comment: I'm gonna give it a try, I hope it will work this time, if Not I think we can file a complaint, you know I guess everything is clear for my case, invitation letter from the company I'm going to visit, expenses will be covered by them and stated in their letter, proof of my PhD study (last year), additional letter from the accommodating company, we also enclosed scientific publications that show our continuous cooperation, letter from my supervisor and the visit is a type of fulfillment for a contract between us and the company.

Comment: I can remove the hotel and flight booking, however, in the application they clearly asked where are you going to stay? And if you just mention the name of a hotel they will likely say no proof  I think I can remove the flights booking